# UIScrollView content view's frame's size doesn't change consistently?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

It seems like when I pinch to zoom on a UIScrollView, the content view's frame size changes with the zoom. If the UIScrollView's zoom is 2, then the frame size of the content view becomes (2*width, 2*height). However, when I zoom the scroll view programmatically using `-setZoomScale:animated`, the content view's frame does not resize.

Does anyone know if this is normal behavior, and if so, how I can programmatically zoom while resizing the frame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a normal behavior. You need to calculate programmatically the new width and height of the scrollview. you can use

> - [yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(yourwidth,yourheight);

and to programatically set scrolling position

> - [yourScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(yourxpos,yourypos) animated:YES/NO];

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Will setContentSize automatically resize the content view's frame? If so, any guess why setZoomScale doesn't?